# Simple digital direction indicator

Tags: logical-deduction

You have three light-sensitive inputs,

Imagine a freely-rotating circle, some portion of which will be painted black (returning 0 to the sensors) and some portion painted white (returning 1)

How can you paint the circle and configure the sensors such that every octant is recognizable from the sensor outputs? For convenience let us label these octants (N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW)

Comment: Could you clarify what this is for? Is it a homework exercise from a university course, a puzzle you found in a book, something that just occurred to you on a whim, or what?

Comment: Is this actually a puzzle? Sounds more like an engineering question.

Comment: A poorly described engineering question at that.

Comment: It is a home assignment I am working on. I think it was a job interview question that the teacher modified.

Comment: The example he gave was a circle that was half black and half white that when you input 0degrees you got north and 180 degrees got south, it had one sensor. If you input 90 degrees you got a question mark because I think it was because of having only one sensor.

Comment: Maybe check out mathSE

Comment: This site is for puzzles and riddles, not help with your homework.

Comment: @Stanmoonie +1 on your comment for clarifying this post. However, as others have pointed out, you're on the wrong site here. But if you've come by "chance", why not stick and become a puzzler and puzzle friend? ;c) Just want to make sure you're not getting the wrong impression of this community. We are friendly and open - but your question is just out of scope here.

Comment: I understand I did stumble unto this area thanks BmyGuest!

Comment: There are 8 binary values that can be represented with 3 bits. Similarly there are 8 directions that you have indicated. However, there is no configuration of sensors and detection areas that will accommodate detection of all three sensors at once _and_ each sensor individually. This means that you have (at best) 7 sensor configurations that you can detect, not the required 8.

Comment: Maybe you should consider changing the context as this is an engineering question!

Comment: @IanMacDonald I don't think you're correct; I think you can do 8. Unless I've misunderstood the question, this is a pretty standard engineering problem, both in the sense that it gets used in classes and textbooks and in the sense that it's a thing people actually need to do.

Answer (score 3):

[I'm a bit uncomfortable answering what is by the OP's admission a homework question. But it's not as if answers to this question are hard to find elsewhere, and the question was reopened after its closure so clearly the Will Of The Community is that it be answered.]

**The "obvious" answer**

> Draw three concentric rings on the circle. We will place each sensor so that it sees one of these rings. The first ring is half white, half black, in the obvious way. The sensor looking at this tells you whether you are (say) in {N,NE,E,SE} or {S,SW,W,NW}. Let's say the former are black and the latter white. Now the next ring switches between white and black at twice the frequency: black for {N,NE} and {S,SW} and white for {E,SE} and {W,NW}. So these two distinguish between 00:{N,NE}, 01:{E,SE}, 10:{S,SW}, 11:{W,NW}. And now the third step is clear: toggle twice as fast again. So we get 8 binary numbers for 8 45-degree ranges of angle. Done.
>  [image]

**The problem with the "obvious" answer**

> Look at what happens as we move from NW to N. All three sensors are switching from white to black simultaneously. In the real world, they will not actually switch at exactly the same time and you will get lots of spurious transitions, the exact order in which they happen depending on fine details of how the sensors are positioned, how sensitive they are, how the whole thing is illuminated, etc.

You can kinda work around this by

> making use of the fact that (if the sensors and whatever is attached to them are quick enough compared with how the wheel moves) these spurious transitions are actually impossible. But it's still rather a mess.

**A better solution**

> You still want a 3-bit binary code. But make it a *Gray code*, where only one bit ever changes at a time. 000 -> 001 -> 011 -> 010 -> 110 -> 111 -> 101 -> 100 -> 000, say. Now as you transition from one sector to the next, just one sensor changes, and there is no opportunity for spurious states to arise "while" changing from one to another.
>  [image]

(Note: Because I am an idiot, my diagrams are reflected left-to-right relative to the textual descriptions. Doesn't seem worth changing. Also, they have some rough edges which are mere rendering infelicities rather than what I am trying to describe.)